# ¿Como hacer la media de un atributo de diferentes objetos del mismo tipo?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

Tengo que realizar la media de un atributo de diferentes objetos, en este caso jugadores de baloncesto, para sacar la media del equipo. He estado mirando y probando con el método **mapToInt** de la interfaz *Stream()* y el método **average** de la interfaz *IntStream,* que creo que es el camino correcto pero no lo consigo. A ver si podéis echarme una mano. Os adjunto código. Os comparto 3 clases:

- Team() donde guardo información de un equipo y los jugadores que contiene.

public class Team implements Serializable{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String shortName, longName, imageSrc, president, sponsor;
private int members, budget, founded;

private Stadium stadium;
private League league;

private final int MAX_PLAYERS = 12;
private final int MIN_PLAYERS = 8;
private List<Player> squad;

private final int NUM_COACHES = 6;
private List<Coach> coaches;    

public Team() throws Exception{
    this("Default", "Team Default", "./", "Dummy", "UOC",1000,1000000,2019);
}

public Team(String shortName, String longName, String imageSrc, String president, String sponsor, int members, int budget, int founded) throws Exception{
    setShortName(shortName);
    setLongName(longName);
    setImageSrc(imageSrc);
    setPresident(president);
    setSponsor(sponsor);
    setMembers(members);
    setBudget(budget);
    setFounded(founded);
    squad = new ArrayList<Player>(MAX_PLAYERS);     
    setupCoaches();
    coaches = new ArrayList<Coach>(NUM_COACHES);
}
//getters y setters
```

A este código tengo que añadirle un método que devuelva un valor *double* de un atributo que tienen todos los jugadores del equipo, ***getSpeedAverage()***:

Esto he intentado sin éxito.

```
    public double getSpeedAverage() {
    double total = 0.00;
    total = squad.stream().mapToInt(Player::attributes.getSpeed).average();
    return total;
}
```

He intentado usar ***stream().mapToInt().average()*** pero sin éxito.

Adjunto la clase Player():

```
public class Player extends Person implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int number, numInternational, injuredWeeks;
private Position position;

private String imageSrc;
private PlayerAttributes attributes;

public Player(String name, String surname, String nick, LocalDate birthdate, Country country, int salary, int cancellationClause, int contractYears, Team team, 
        int number, int numInternational, int height, double weight, int speed, int defense, int jump, int energy, int ft, int fg2p, int fg3p, int rebounds, 
        int assists, Position position, String imageSrc ) throws Exception{

    super(name, surname, nick, birthdate, country, salary, cancellationClause, contractYears, team);        
    setNumber(number);  
    setNumInternational(numInternational);
    setPosition(position);
    setInjuriedWeeks(0);
    setImageSrc(imageSrc);

    attributes= new PlayerAttributes(height, weight, speed, defense, jump, energy, ft, fg2p, fg3p, rebounds, assists);
}

//getters y setters
```

Y la clase donde se guardan sus atributos, donde se guarda el atributo ***Speed*** que queremos obtener de todos los jugadores es la clase ***PlayerAttributes()***:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int height, speed, defense, jump, energy, ft, fg2p, fg3p, rebounds, assists;

private double weight;

public PlayerAttributes(int height, double weight, int speed, int defense, int jump, int energy,
        int ft, int fg2p, int fg3p, int rebounds, int assists) throws Exception{

    setHeight(height);
    setWeight(weight);
    setSpeed(speed);
    setDefense(defense);
    setJump(jump);
    setEnergy(energy);
    setFt(ft);
    setFg2p(fg2p);
    setFg3p(fg3p);
    setRebounds(rebounds);
    setAssists(assists);
}

//getters y setters
```

Con toda esta información espero que alguien pueda ayudarme ya que he probado diferentes cosas y no me sale. Espero haber expresado bien el problema. Gracias.

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado con el `mapToInt`, quizá solo es algún detalle que se te escapó y por eso no funciona.

Comment: editado! A ver si así queda más claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que has hecho está en el camino correcto, solo con un par de correcciones.

**1 -** El uso de referencias a métodos no puede encadenarse ni con otras referencias a métodos ni con llamadas tradicionales a métodos. En tu caso esto sería incorrecto y produce un error de compilación

```
Player::attributes.getSpeed
```

Además no se pueden hacer referencia a atributos de una clase, solo a métodos, por lo que `Player::attributes` no es válido. Lo que debes hacer es referenciar al método `getAttibutes()`: `Player::getAttributes`.

**2 -** El método `IntStream.average()` retorna un `OptionalDouble` y no un `double` en sí. Por tanto no puedes retornar el valor que devuelve si tu método espera retornar un `double`.

De acuerdo a lo explicado en el punto 1, podemos tener dos soluciones, dependiendo de como te guste más trabajar.

**Solución 1: Sin usar referencias a métodos**

```
    public double getSpeedAverage() {
        return squad.stream()
                .mapToInt(p -> p.getAttributes().getSpeed())
                .average()
                .orElse(0);
    }
```

**Solución 2: Usando referencias a métodos**

```
    public double getSpeedAverage() {
        return squad.stream()
                .map(Player::getAttributes)
                .mapToInt(PlayerAttributes::getSpeed)
                .average()
                .orElse(0);
    }
```

En ambas soluciones hago uso del método `orElse()` para asegurarme que siempre voy a retornar 0 en caso de no haberse podido calcular el promedio (por ejemplo si la lista de jugadores está vacía) ya que de otro modo podría lanzarse una excepción de tipo `NoSuchElementException` al llamar a `getAsDouble()` para obtener el valor  del promedio.